# How do I set up a development environment that is identical to the pythonanywhere production environment?

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to set up a development environment that is identical to the pythonanywhere live (production) environment.

I uploaded a basic test site an discovered I have to change a few settings when I upload which I would definitely forget to do sometime.

Ideally what i'd like to do is run a script from my command line that would create a fresh development environment for me to work with that completes all the setup tasks in one go, for example; set up a virtual environment, install all dependencies.

My questions are:

1. What do I need to set up? I'm working with django, so far I would have; set up virtual environment, install all dependencies (django and all the other things i would normally work with), potentially create all my project files and set up databases (if i didn't want a blank slate)
2. Can someone point me in the right direction to find out how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a requirement.txt file

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

on the production server just use:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This will setup your production environment as the same as your development environment.
more at doc: [pip documentaion](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/)